Conditional background pattern on <GeoJSON> object in React + Leaflet.js
I have a React app, drawing a map with components like this:
const MyGeoJsonComponent: React.FC<GeoJSONProps> = (props) => {
...
return (
    <GeoJSON
      ref={geoRef}
      key={Math.random()}
      data={feature}
      style={getStyle}
      onEachFeature={onEachFeature}
      {...feature}
    >
    ...
    </GeoJSON>
);};

So far I have each GeoJSON object colored using the "style={}" property, however I would like to have a background with some pattern (stripes for example) based on certain condition.
If I try to set any "background:" properties to the style fillColor property - all GeoJSON objects default to grey background.
Is there a way to do this in using Leaflet.js or any other third-party library?
===================
UPDATE: I have found a workaround that "works" for me. I am using the styled-components library to create a global style, which I use to set a conditional selector for the GeoJSON objects I need and set their background to a gradient.
const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle<{ $color?: string; $customProp?: string }>`
[customAttr='${({ $customProp }) => $customProp}'] {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
    45deg,
    ${({ $color }) => $color}33,
    ${({ $color }) => $color}33 10px,
    ${({ $color }) => $color}CC 5px,
    ${({ $color }) => $color}CC 15px
  );
}
`;

...

And then I can include it conditionally when I render my components:
      { someCondition && (
        <GlobalStyle
          $color={properties.color}
          $customProp={properties.customProp}
        />
      )}

Hope this helps someone.

The following snippet illustrates how you can style Leaflet paths based on GeoJSON properties:


const SVGwithPatterns = L.SVG.extend({
  _initContainer() {
    L.SVG.prototype._initContainer.apply(this, arguments);
    var defs = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "defs");
    defs.innerHTML = document.getElementById("defs").textContent;
    this._container.firstElementChild.before(defs);
  }
});
const map = L.map(document.body).setView([49.3, 8.7], 11);
L.tileLayer("https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {}).addTo(map);
L.geoJSON({
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "fillPattern": "blue-striped"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "LineString",
      "coordinates": [
        [8.69, 49.29],
        [8.69, 49.31],
        [8.71, 49.29],
        [8.69, 49.29]
      ]
    }
  }]
}, {
  style(feature) {
    var style = {};
    if (feature.properties.fillPattern) {
      style.fill = true;
      style.fillOpacity = 0.5;
      style.fillColor = `url(#${feature.properties.fillPattern})`;
    }
    return style;
  },
  renderer: new SVGwithPatterns()
}).addTo(map);
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha256-p4NxAoJBhIIN+hmNHrzRCf9tD/miZyoHS5obTRR9BMY=" crossorigin="" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha256-20nQCchB9co0qIjJZRGuk2/Z9VM+kNiyxNV1lvTlZBo=" crossorigin=""></script>
<script id="defs" type="text/xml">
  <pattern id="blue-striped" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="5" height="5" viewBox="0 0 1 1">
    <path d="M 0.5 0 L 0.5 1" stroke-width="0.5" stroke="blue" />
  </pattern>
  <pattern id="blue-solid" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="5" height="5" viewBox="0 0 1 1">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" stroke="none" fill="blue" />
  </pattern>
</script>

<body style="position: fixed; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;"></body>



A subclass of the L.SVG renderer has been used to allow fill properties that reference a pattern. This example contains two patterns blue-striped and blue-solid.

Thank you for your comment. I have updated my question to illustrate how I render my component. Could you tell me if I can use your approach to set a background pattern for my components?

Sorry, that must be answered by a react expert (which I am not). But I assume that react is powerful enough to support that.
